# Has any philosopher claimed that reality is a simulation, and the evil genius wants us to stay alive, in order to explain what seems like a miracle?

Tags: metaphysics, reality, good-and-evil, solipsism

Has any philosopher claimed that reality is a simulation, and the evil genius wants us to stay alive, in order for that philosopher to explain what *seems* like a miracle?

Would anyone ever admit to such a ridiculous belief? If that were true, how would it change our "metaphysics" (which is, incidentally, not my word)?

However dim that one sounds, I would be highly interested in hearing a very good counter-argument to that intuition. Perhaps it is too solipsistic? Or do we **know** that the evil genius would, then, be ***mad***, and so not in control of our reality?

In effect, I may be looking for a definitive reason to believe that history is real, because it's that or an intolerably "queer" (in Mackey's sense) madness: so that he, the evil genius, would be God after-all. Else he would not be omnipotent.

Comment: Many theists would probably not say that a created universe was a simulation: the incarnation of Christ sort of precludes that.

Comment: Well obviously you're referring to Descartes. The creator of our simulation is not looking for philosophers to discover they're in a simulation..natural selection produces the best results.. but it's tediously slow. What if you could speed it up.. run 15bn years out in a few days.. give the simulation the starting equation.. boom.. a universe.. let it run... Intelligent life... 10 billion minds trying to cure mortality.. and Invent FTL travel. Who knows what the creator is looking for? But it's unlikely to be a philosopher.

Comment: @Richard is the creator human?

Comment: @confused IMO no.. but the intelligence need not be that much more advanced than our own . If we manage to survive 5000 years at this exponential rate of technological advancement. With the help of the synthetic intelligences we create.. might reach that capability ourselves.

Comment: i don't like the idea that there are super human powers or whatever that get the good, as opposed to us! @Richard

Comment: @confused well don't think of it like that. To them we're the result of a short running but complex simulation.. but to us time runs as we see it. Even if we are a simulation.. this is our reality.. and there's no escaping it. You have to play the cards you're dealt.

Comment: so they're evil? beyond good and evil? values are values @Richard

Comment: Re: the wording of your question: what's the miracle?

Comment: @elliotsvensson i don't believe in miracles

Comment: Oh, of course.  What's the thing that could possibly seem like a miracle?

Comment: @elliotsvensson thanks. i believe in you too

Comment: @confused No they're not evil.. they're absolutely chaotic neutral to use the D&D term. They don't care about us.. they're waiting for some event.. that may never happen. We could be the plaything of a teenage sentient crab. The creator may have  almost no control over our universe other than it's starting parameters... we might be it's 50th attempt. What I'm saying is that our creator matters as much to us as we to it... That is... Not at all. It matters not WHY the demon did it.

Comment: the limits of our language ("they are evil") are the limits of our world? @Richard

Comment: @confused The limits of our world are what science is trying to discover.. they are defined by the nature of our reality... Which we don't understand yet.

Comment: @Richard 'science' is just a very reliable technique imho

Comment: @confused it's the only reliable technique... No other method of inquiry produces meaningful results.. Sadly sometimes even science doesn't.

Comment: You ask for a remarkably specific scenario.  May I ask you be a bit more specific: what does it mean to you for reality to be a "simulation?"  It's a popular buzz word these days, but, as they say, the evil genius is in the details.

Comment: @confused I think on reflection what I'm saying is that Descartes 'evil' (Dr O) is a misnomer. The simulation seems real.   Because it *is* real. They're not trying to trick us. This is the reality we live in.

Comment: @confused and I missed your point about them having the good. What if they dont. What if they're a simulation... And they found out.. and decided to give it a go themselves? But if not.. what if they are in a real universe but it's not fathomable.. good... Is simply not understandable... None of it matters.. this.. is what we have.. and beer is tasty.

Comment: @confused - The idea that science is the only method that produces reliable results would only be true if you define science in a way no physicist I know of would happily accept. Besides, philosophy produces reliable results. It's results are so reliable they have not changed since the dawn of time. One of its results is that we cannot be sure from the evidence of our senses that we are not living in a simulation. No amount of science is going to change this reliable result. .

Comment: @confused  After this extended discussion, it is probably best to rephrase the question.

Comment: oh hey @MarkAndrews i'll get to that later, thanks for the note

Comment: @PeterJ i didn't say that "science is the only method that produces reliable results" i said it was very reliable. i would agree that not all empirical knowledge is "scientific" in any meaningful sense of that word

Comment: @confused - A thousand apologies. My comment was meant for Richard.

Comment: @PeterJ science *is* philosophy and vice versa. My point is that the peculiar mix of abduction.. empiricism.. peer review and selective rationalism... That is science has prevented my early death through antibiotics.. and given me a cogent model of reality that religion or metaphysics had not.

Comment: The [eastern story](http://ridingaspiral.blogspot.com/2011/03/magicians-dinner-party.html) (so-called) of the magician. Note particularly the last para of the second version.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a few good tests of the external world that I'd like to pass along to you, and they all have to do with *other people*.

1) Kindness.  Have others granted you kindness when you didn't deserve it, particularly when it cost them something?  How would a mad string-puller make that happen?

2) Beauty.  Take a look at a sunset, the stars, a thundercloud, the colors on the surface of a soap bubble... or listen to Air on the G String by Bach or anything that you like.  Does this make you more or less credulous that what you see is a veneer over a dim despairing reality?

3) Creation.  Look at a bug, or swing a feather, or just look at your hand.  Did you know that your skin gets slightly moist when it feels a very slick surface, in order to increase the traction of your fingerprints in order to pick the item up?  Would a mad scientist, as a sort of higher-form of videogame designer, have gone to the trouble to create such stuff?

4) Literature.  Read a long novel, something grown-up or even Harry Potter (I'm reading the Gulag Archipelago).  How did that story get there?  Does it cause you to form beliefs that benefit the mad string-puller or does it influence your beliefs toward a realistic version of your observed universe?

Comment: these are all aesthetic things, and so, i feel, at root pragmatic.

Comment: Can you please expand on that?

Comment: Oh OK. 2 3 and 4 are, prima facie, aesthetic, about beauty. and, i think, kindness is also beautiful. I think I just have my answer though... I do believe that other people exist, and we were not born at the exact same time.

Comment: Here is a good one... One can't have thought without time. One cannot be at a place, without also being at a time (space and time are inextricable)... You are thinking now..Ergo space is real.. and by extension... Everything in it... No need to thank me... It's my pleasure.

Comment: @Richard - Sorry, but it isn't that easy. Those who say that what is observed in time and space is not really real also say that the observer is not really real. So observation proves nothing.  Thoughts require time, as you say. but all this means is that when we reduce time and space to the Ultimate we must also reduce Mind. And this is exactly what mysticism does.

Comment: @PeterJ I'm not sure how anyone can deny that they are thinking.

Comment: @Richard - Nor me. They'd have to be thinking on order to deny it. But as the poet Paul Valery says 'Sometimes I think, sometime I am'  The point is simply that we cannot argue that time and space are real (metaphysically real or irreducible) by pointing to any space-time phenomena, not even thought, since those who deny the true reality of space-time also deny the true reality of thinking beings.  .  .

Comment: @PeterJ yes.. I wasn't really claiming to have found an idealist proof of materialism. But.... We have to ask what thinking is. Can you ever think yourself to work in the morning? Or think yourself into two different people? Not only do we have to accept we are thinking... But that our thoughts have rules. It I in accepting that our thoughts of where and when we are.. seem to indicate space and time are linked.

Comment: @Richard - Ha. As someone who writes these days I can think myself to work. But yes, I'm with you more or less. It is a much-overlooked issue that thought requires time, for the question of whether time is fundamental has profound and damaging consequences for mind-only metaphysical theories. It is an issue of considerable importance in mysticism. .

Comment: @PeterJ yes.. I know that I'm simply trying to find a way of explaining some fairly dogmatic and deeply entrenched opinions on what reality is.. that I have because of a lifelong STEM education.. for years I absolutely rejected any form of solipsism. Now in my less certain age I find myself revisiting some of this.

Comment: @Richard - I admire your ability to question long-held views. I'm being told off for chatting but would be happy to explore this further elsewhere. .